# How to include parent's sources in an assembly

Tags: maven

I have an assembly executed in my top level project (the parent).
I extract all the sources to allow the client to compile the project.

The problem is that all is extracted except the parent project it self (as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-source-inclusion-simple.html)).
Of course this is not really a problem because it does not contains sources but it is needed to compile the project from the extracted sources.

So how can I include the parent in his own assembly?

Comment: Have you used the defined descriptor: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#src

Comment: Hello, no I'm using my own assembly with modules to retrieve sources. my problem is from the doc here [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-module-set-topics.html) chapter Including and Excluding Modules using a ModuleSet. it says you can browse into the childs but nothing about the parent.

Comment: You want to include the parent project's `pom.xml` in the assembly, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes this is the idea. I know it could be done with the fileset but would be great to do something in one time ex:'<moduleSets>
  <moduleSet>
    <includes>
    <include>groupID:rootArtifact</include>
   </includes>' but it does not find himself. Has to use 'groupID:firstChildLevelArtifact'

Comment: Agreed. I included the parent as a module in an assembly run from a parent project, with `-X` on the cmd line. The assembly output includes `[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:  o  'com.company:theParent'`.  Looks like Maven is cross-referencing the `<modules>` list from the parent with the module includes. It doesn't find the parent and ignores it.  The docs discuss using a separate child project just for building assemblies in multimodule builds, don't know if that helps or not. I would probably just use `fileSet` or `file` if it were me.

Comment: Finally, I've added a fileset only for the parent: <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
    <excludes><exclude></exclude></excludes>
    <includes><include>*pom.xml</include><include>src/**</include></includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets> I've kept module for child's sources which works quite well. Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've added a fileset only for the parent:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <excludes>
            <exclude></exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>*pom.xml</include>
            <include>src/**</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <includes>
            <include>com.xxx</include>
            <include>com.xxx</include>
        </includes>
        <sources>
            <excludeSubModuleDirectories>false</excludeSubModuleDirectories>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/target/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

I've kept module for child's sources which works quite well. 
Thanks for all